# Why does the stored procedure execution time vary for parameters?

Tags: sql-server

When I execute a stored procedure for some parameters, it is taking more time. For some parameters, it is taking 1 sec, but after setting `commandobject.timeout=0`, there is no time out. I want know why execution time differs for some parameters.

Comment: Parameter sniffing is likely - also you can check execution plans and time/io statistics

Comment: This is a very good article by Erland Sommarskog: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Answer (score 0):

The execution time depends on the amount of data processed/used by the SP. The amount of data is belong to the parameters. That's why execution time differs for some parameters. For example, there is a SP used for calculating monthly sale report. The input parameter is the month of the report. If there are two months: in the first month there are thousands of bills and in the second month, there are a few bills, then you will see the difference between the execution times when the inputs are the two months.
I hope this helps.